# why cpp thread of instance member-fcn reset the member-variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading

my simple test code is as:

```cpp
// t.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class test
{
private:

public:
    void fcn1();
    void fcn2();
    uint8_t i = 0;

};


void test::fcn1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(999));
        std::cout << "hihi " << (float)i++ << std::endl;
    }
}


void test::fcn2()
{
    std::cout << "yoyo " << (float)i++ << std::endl;
}

test t;

std::thread tt(&test::fcn1, t);

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        t.fcn2();
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

compile and run by `g++ ./t.cpp -o t -lpthread; ./t`, result is like

```bash
hihi 0
yoyo 0
hihi 1
yoyo 1
hihi 2
yoyo 2
hihi 3
...
```

i expect the result should be:

```bash
hihi 0
yoyo 1
hihi 2
yoyo 3
hihi 4
yoyo 5
...
```

looks like the cpp thread of instance member-fcn reset the member-variable?
why not the `i` is shared by `fcn1` and `fcn2`?

the demo code is a simplification of my real useage, but faces the same problem,

what's wrong with my code? thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread):

> `args_copy...` are objects of types `std::decay<Args>::type...` and constructed from `std::forward<Args>(args)....`
>
> ...
>
> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g., with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).

So arguments are copied by default, including the `this` argument to a pointer-to-member function. You can wrap it in `std::ref` to get a reference explicitly.

```
std::thread tt(&test::fcn1, std::ref(t));
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread` makes a copy of all of its constructor arguments.  That means that `std::thread tt(&test1::fcn1, t)` makes a copy of `t` and calls `fcn1` on the copy.

To avoid that you need to pass a pointer or `std::reference_wrapper` to `t`:

```
std::thread tt(&test1::fcn1, &t);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3176a2d9fc26be04)

---

Note that even with this change your program's behavior is undefined since you have a data race on `t.i`.  You should use `std::atomic<uint8_t>` instead to avoid that race.

Comment: thanks for this more detailed explain